# mongoose не сохраняет

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Делаю все стандартно, по туториалу:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://myDomian/test");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var TestSchema = new Schema({
    title     : { type: String }
});
var Test = mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
var test = new Test({
    title: req.body.title
});
test.save();
```

Смотрел через командную строку "mongo" - база данных "test" существует, моделей, объектов, коллекций нет.

Вот так вывожу модели из mogoose в express'e:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://myDomian/test");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var TestSchema = new Schema({
    title     : { type: String }
});
var Test = mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
Test.findById(1, '', { lean: true },  function(err, data) {
    if (data) {res.send("43gredata"); }
});

});
```

Comment: var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect("127.0.0.1:27017/test");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var TestSchema = new Schema({
    title     : { type: String }
});
var Test = mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
var test = new Test({
    title: 'Hello'
});
test.save();

У меня так работает, проверь req.body.title

Comment: На test.save навесьте коллбек и там console.log, что пишет?

Comment: Стоп.. вы ищете по id=1, но он по умолчанию присваивает id длинные, вроде как случайно сгенерированные, не удивительно, что 1 не находит

Comment: Андрей, это пример одного из многих способов, которыми пытался найти. Хз, может я порт забыл написать. Надо посмотреть. Но походу дела проблема в администрировании, настроил сервак криво.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какая-то сплошная путаница с переменными. Вы вот такой файл для начала просто запустите (ибо Node.js есть "runtime ecosystem") - он в базу данных запишет документ.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://myDomian/test");
var TestSchema = db.Schema({
  title: { type: String }
});
var Test = db.model('test', TestSchema);

var test = new Test({
  title: "Title"
});
test.save();
```

А потом это всё надо разделять как-то: типа connection где-то отдельным файлом, модели отдельно, а уж в обработчиках только обращение от модели (которая сама уж и законнектилась и т.д.). Короче, в учебниках всё написано.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема была как раз в коде, окружающем операции с бд. А еще оказывается, надо писать 127.0.0.1:27017 при подключении к бд. Я же писал свой внешний айпишник сервера.